# How would I go about downloading and unzipping a zip archive using Java?

Tags: java, file, download, zip, extract

I made a little JPanel tool for myself and a friend of mine, and it has image icons on it. It loads the images from "Images" folder in user.home, but I want it to, when it opens, check if that directory exists, and if it doesn't, download the zip archive containing the folder, and extract it to user.home. Some people have told me it's not even possible, but I think otherwise. I just can't think of a way to do so. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Your question involves a lot of steps, and we'll need to know which step in particular you might be stuck on. If your answer is "all of them", then you might be here too early since the question is quite broad. In that case, consider breaking down your problem into its smaller constituent steps and trying to solve each step one at a time. Then if you get stuck again you can ask a much more specific and better question, one with your code.

Answer (score 4):

It's actually pretty easy, just add Apache Commons IO and [zip4j](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/) as a dependency in your project in order to use `FileUtils` and Zip utilities.

You can use Maven or whatever you want for that.

It's as easy as splitting what you want in three steps, checking if directory exists, then if not downloading the file, then extracting it.

```
String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
File imagesPath = new File(home + "/Images");
boolean exists = imagesPath.exists();
if (!exists) {
    // create directory
    imagesPath.mkdir();
    // download
    String zipPath = home + "/Images.zip";
    FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL("http://url/Images.zip"), new File(zipPath));
    // unzip
    try {
         new ZipFile(zipPath).extractAll(home + "/Images");
    } catch (ZipException e) {
         // do something useful
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```